# Positioning of Elements inside a <div>

Tags: css, html, position

I've hit a snag in html and css.
I created a div and wanted to put a logo image on its left and a button link on its right but stubborn css insists on making it move on to separate lines ,I used float:left and float:right.

Comment: Can you provide some code or create a fiddle so we can see your code?

Comment: Im sorry but I lost all of my code , and I've just given the specs down in my comment

Comment: Okay, see my answer. You mean something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QFEKN/

```
<div>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c5b9fb1230ea2fe0dc96151cba3098d5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" style='float: left' />
    <button>Link</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I want the img far left and the links far right and the button link was created with padding of a list item link and box shadows.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

Put a div on your img and button and set width to 100%. Then `float` your image and your button. I updated the fiddle of thewheat: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFEKN/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Your CSS

#box
{
width:100%;
}


#logo
{
float:left;
width:50%;
/*padding and Margin according to your need*/
}



#buttons

{

float:right;
width:50%;
}




Your HTML

<div id ="box">

   <div id ="logo">
         /*your img file here */
</div>


<div id="buttons">
/* Your links/buutons */

</div>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the thing you can do here is that you create a table put your logo in first cell of the row and next cell you can add your link, after that you can set float/margin to the positioning you want..hope that helps

Comment: <table border="0" width=100% >
    <tr>
        <td width=50%>
            //your code to put image logo
        </td>
        <td align="right">
                //your link
        </td>
     <tr>
</table>
..

Comment: I never use tables for positioning (I despise them)

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use "float property". without it things will not work well in all browsers and then you will get browsers issues too.
>   Do this , This will work fine.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/S2rnm/848/)

```
img
{
float:left;
width:100px;
}
button
{
float:right;
width:100px;
}
```